# In globalize/mobility gem: can I use other context parameters than the locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, globalize, mobility

I would like to extend the [mobility gem](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) so that I can show different text based on the context such as a region or industry.

Example:
User is speaking Spanish and is in the Automotive industry

=> we would show him a specific text for the Automotive industry in Spanish

Comment: Tailoring content to users in this way is beyond the scope of internationalization. Would it be possible? Maybe. But it's not what Mobility is designed to do and I wouldn't approach the problem from that end. Instead tailor the content in your business domain logic and *then* use mobility to internationalize it.

Comment: Just as an idea: How about creating something like "es_auto" und use this as a "language" in mobility? You can use your own locale in mobilty apart from the Rails-Locale - see https://github.com/shioyama/mobility#setting-the-locale

Comment: @zaphodbln_ interesting... a bit hacky but could be useful!